# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_funcallv after OSX Mavericks update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bash, osx-mavericks

Rounding the corner on debugging my environment after installing Mavericks. Everything is working fine up until I try to start my server on an app. When I go to localhost:3000 I get this error in my terminal:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_funcallv
Referenced from: /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_funcallv
Referenced from: /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I've googled around and looked at similar errors, seems perhaps my Ruby gem is conflicting with a previous install? Nothing I've tried so far is helping. I've looked at my bash files to see if there's something I need to edit but nothing seems obvious. I've bundle installed with no errors but get the above message when I try to run the server. When I run Ruby -v I get:

```
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

Halp.

Comment: Apologies, I was just editing. Code should now be visible. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to run `ruby version 2.0.0` with ruby gems compiled from `ruby version 2.1.0`. Do `rvm use 2.1.0` and run server. See what happens.

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said and I'm getting a new error: Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.0'.
Using /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0.  The temporary fix works. But I'm unclear how to resolve the issue, I believe it's the PATH in my bash file?

Comment: Fixed. I updated my gems and added 'source ~/.profile' to the bottom of my bash_profile and all seems well.